# Jquery get request use data again

Tags: jquery

With a JQuery GET request, I'm generating Google Authenticator secret (this part works fine).
After the Secret has been generated, I'm hiding the generated ID and display the one time password for submit. Inside the one time password, I have a button. Now I do a simple alert to test the button but this button is not working.
Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong in my JQuery script:

```
$( "#enable_authenticator" ).click(function() {
    $.get("{{route('generateSecret')}}",
    function(data, status){
        $('#Authenticator_alert').hide();
        $('#enable_authenticator').hide();
        $( "#set_authenticator" ).html('<center>'+data[0]+'<br>'+'Your Authenticator Secret is: <strong>'+data[1]+'</strong> <br> <input type="text" placeholder="One Time Password" id="onetimepassword" class="form-control"><br> <button type="button" id="submitOneTimePassword" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button></center>');
    });
});

$('#submitOneTimePassword').click(function() {
    alert('here');
});
```

ID: **submitOneTimePassword** is not working.

Comment: From this amount of code, the `$(...).click()` event looks correct. Could you add more from the HTML, so we can get a better picture of this?

Comment: `$('#submitOneTimePassword').on('click', function(...`

Comment: @pavel That is effectively no different than what OP is already using with the shortcut method `.click()`. That selector does not exist at run time

Answer (score 2):

That is because your element with the ID `submitOneTimePassword` is not present at runtime. Use event delegation instead (i.e. [using `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)), so that you capture the click event bubbling from the dynamically added element. Since the parent `#set_authenticator` is already present at runtime, you can listen to the bubbled up click event from it instead:

```
$('#set_authenticator').on('click', '#submitOneTimePassword', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```